# OpenId + remember me / staying logged in

Tags: cookies, authentication, openid

I have a question as to how / what the best approaches are to using OpenId and also providing the ability to stay logged in.

If i look at Stackoverflow for example i have logged in using Google and if i close by browser and come back it still has me as logged in.

**However**, i am not logged into Google and moreoever I have **removed** stackoverflow from the list of authorised services which have access to your Google account. I would naively expect that stackoverflow would prompt me to login again but it doesn't.

So my question is, what are the best practices regarding OpenId and remembering authenticated users across sessions?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

OpenID is still pretty new and several relying parties are trying out new and different ways to implement OpenID.  There is a work in progress [best practices document for relying parties](http://wiki.openid.net/Relying-Party-Best-Practices) hosted by the OpenID foundation.  In particular, they address the question of cookies and session lengths in their [last section](http://wiki.openid.net/Relying-Party-Best-Practices#StoreprimaryOpenIDinacookieandcheckimmediateatnextsession).  Definitely an interesting idea to use persistent claimed_id cookies rather than persistent session cookies in order to make the user's life easier -- they only have to log out of their OP and close the browser.

Personally I find the behavior you're describing on StackOverflow pretty natural.  If OpenID were out of the picture and you were logged into a username/password web site on two different computers with a persistent cookie (a very common scenario), and you changed your password on one, I wouldn't be surprised if the other computer still had me logged in.  You *could* call that a security hole, but it's still normal practice.  So normal in fact that Gmail recently added a display at the bottom of your Inbox screen that tells you where else you're logged in and gives you the opportunity to invalidate their session cookie.

I would suggest that a similar approach could be taken by any RP, regardless of the authentication method.  And that would probably mitigate the security concern you have.

Comment: 4 years later, checking if there's any progress on this?

Comment: 4 years later, yeah I believe there was, there are comprehensive [specs](http://openid.net/developers/specs/) here.

Answer (score 4):

Stack overflow probably uses a cookie to remember you as user number xyz or session id 1234. After authentication, OpenID has nothing at all to do with the session anymore. SO doesn't have the ability to see if you are still logged in to Google so this seems only natural.

Comment: i understand/ appreciate it is using its own cookie but i would expect that at least some periodic check would be made against google since i have removed stack overflow from the list of authorized services against my google account.  Under this setup someone could quite easily come and use my machine and post content within stack overflow when i have said that i don't want this to happen in Google.

Comment: You have indicated that you don't want stack overflow to authenticate to your google account anymore. It's not authenticating because you already did that some time ago.

What you want impossible without requiring you to log in again periodically.

Comment: The thing is though, from a user perspective i think this makes OpenId somewhat contradictory. You can have one place to 'provide your logon process' but you don't have one place to control which sites can and can't use it.  Ths potentially means that when other sites have, in effect, retained sufficient information from you logging on they then don't need to authenticate you again.  Anyway my question wasn't directed at SO per se, but rather at what the recommended best practices regarding OpenId & 'staying logged in' solutions is / are.